# Mouse Problems with Ubuntu

Tags: mouse

I am a new user to the Ubuntu for a Home PC (I have used the server software and PuttY).

So first I will explain my problem and tell you what my specs and mouse is.

My Problem is that say I have Firefox open, I cannot click outside of firefox and I cannot even click the Close button, but when running Windows I get no problems, this is a new PC I have tried updating and upgrading - No harm in trying again.

Ubuntu 13.10

**AMD FX-4100 Quad Core 3.6GHz** -
**4GB Ram** -
**1TB HDD** -
**Cyborg Mad Catz R.A.T3** - 
**Cyborg v.5 Keyboard** -
**ASUS M578AL-M LX V2 (MotherBoard)**

Thanks, All help appreciated. I love Ubuntu and want to keep using it but this is a major problem.

Comment: Is this a fresh install, or at least a system that is still using the same window manager and other GUI components used after a fresh install?

Comment: This is a complete Fresh install.

Comment: Try getting all of the updates available. You can download Synaptic via the Software Center and in Synaptic, click "Reload". Once done, select all updates and click "Apply". You are not having a hardware problem, so it must be some bug in Saucy. When I installed Saucy, I immediately got updates, so I would not notice this issue.

Comment: I'll give this a go, I dont know if it will fix this or not.

Comment: that did not fix this, Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this still happening?  I'm having a similar (maybe same) problem, and have more info.  After some more testing, I may open a new topic.